# Isolate output of right channel or left channel of audio blob using a panner (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, wavesurfer.js

I am using `wavesurfer.js` to display and play an audio blob and am looking for a way to isolate the audio output of the right channel and left channel. I tried adding a `StereoPannerNode` but it seems like both channels play out of whichever side I pan to and doesn't effectively isolate the right channel at +1 or left channel at -1. Any help with this issue would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To isolate a channel of a signal with the Web Audio API you could use the [`ChannelSplitterNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelSplitterNode) which allows you to connect the individual channels of a signal separately.

A simple example to isolate the left channel (channel at index 0) from a stereo signal might look like this:

```
const channelSplitterNode = new ChannelSplitterNode(
    audioContext,
    { numberOfOutputs: 2 }
);

input
    .connect(channelSplitterNode)
    .connect(output, 0);
```

Jordan Eldredge once wrote a nice article which explains the difference between the `StereoPannerNode` and what he calls a `StereoBalanceNode`. [Implementing a Robust Web Audio API Balance Node](https://jordaneldredge.com/blog/implementing-a-robust-web-audio-api-balance-node/)